# How to apply wpf data binding on the fly at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datepicker

I have been working on as assignment where WPF GUI is genereated at runtime. Runtime generated GUI is consumed by another wpf application. Template generator application allows to create GUI and save it as xml (xaml is actually xml) using XAMLWriter. Consumer application use XAMLReader to add tamplate on GUI. Now i want some sort of binding among controls in generated template.

Requirement : Date on first Datepicker = 2015/01/02 and textbox Text = 1 then date on second datepicker must be 2015/01/03. If textbox text = -1 the date on second date picker must have 2015/01/01.

How i could achieve this at runtime. Nothing needs to hard code as generated template is generated from another application. We have some specific values on Tag property of control which indicates us which three controls are involved and which datepicker is source ,which datepicker is destination and which textbox text needs to used.

Is it possible to use Dynamic data binding? or how this can be accomplished

Comment: _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: This sounds like something that can be handled fully with data triggers, if you the values are known ahead of time and all you're doing is toggling between them.

Comment: Do you use an ObjectDataProvider in the beginning of generated XAML? What type of object uses that Datepicker, a DataTemplate or the Grid of XAML? Is there more DataRow what should be binded or just separated datum?
You should be more specific to see what is the problem you found.

Comment: First of all, **if there is no code behind then a simple Load is enough**. `System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);` see a sample autogenerated i.g.cs for more details. 
If there is code behind (in a partial class) then it's little bit hard: Generate a partial C# class the same way `i.g.cs` files are auto-generated (load instructions are inside). `My answer bello can be used if no codebehind`

Answer (score 1):

=> Rename your Xml file to Xaml

```
<UserControl ...>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Background="Aqua">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label}" Width="200" Height="40"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

=> This is the class you will be merging with the code-behind if there is

```
public class XamlLoadedType:UserControl, IComponentConnector
{
    private bool _contentLoaded; 
    public void InitializeComponent() {
        if (_contentLoaded) {
            return;
        }
        _contentLoaded = true;
        var resourceLocater = new System.Uri(_uri, System.UriKind.Relative);            
        Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);
    }

    void IComponentConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target) {
        this._contentLoaded = true;
    }

    string _uri ;
    public XamlLoadedType(string uri)
    {
        _uri = uri;
        InitializeComponent();
    }   
}
```

=> The main window and it's viewmodel:

```
<Window ...>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding LoadCommand}" Width="100" Height="50">Load</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding LoadedContent}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
public class MainViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand LoadCommand { get; set; }
    object _loadedContent;
    public object LoadedContent
    {
        get { return _loadedContent; }
        set {
            SetField(ref _loadedContent, value, "LoadedContent");
        }

    }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        LoadCommand = new RelayCommand(Load, ()=>true);
    }

    private void Load()
    {
        var xamlLoaded = new XamlLoadedType("/WPFApplication1;component/XamlToLoad.xml.xaml");
        xamlLoaded.DataContext = new { Label = "HeyDude" };
        LoadedContent = xamlLoaded;

    }
}
```

Voilà